# GeoServer OpenLayers Attribute Slider

Tags: geoserver, javascript, openlayers, timeslider

I'm developing a website with 2 divs of maps using different data from my GeoServer.

[image: Current status.img]

My data is in a range from 1980 to 2016 and looks like this:

[image: GeoServer attribute table.img]

My idea is to change the views with a slider using the .updateParams() function.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Map Scripte-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <!--Slider Scripte-->
    <!--Titel-->
    <title>Final Map</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #2F5873;">
    <div>
        <p id="map_gdp" class="map_gdp"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="map_cotwo" class="map_cotwo"></p></pö>
    </div>
    <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1980" max="2016" value="2000" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Date: <span id="date_value"></span></p>
    </div>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Map_gdp View
var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([13, 52]),
    zoom: 4,
});

//gdp WMS-Layer
var gdplayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
    opacity: 1,
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8585/geoserver/abschluss_gdd/wms?',
        params: { 'LAYERS': '   abschluss_gdd:gdp', 'TILED': true, 'Version': '1.1.0' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: null,
        // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
        transition: 0.5
    })
});

//gdp WFS-Layer
var gdp_style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
        width: 1,
    }),
});

var gdp_styleLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://localhost:8585/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=abschluss_gdd:cotwo&outputFormat=application/json',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
        return gdp_style;
    },
});


//Map_gdp generation
var map1 = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map_gdp',
    view: view,
    layers: [
        gdplayer,
        gdp_styleLayer,
    ]
});

//cotwo WMS-Layer
var cotwolayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    // Countries have transparency, so do not fade tiles:
    opacity: 1,
    visible: true,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8585/geoserver/abschluss_gdd/wms?',
        params: { 'LAYERS': 'abschluss_gdd:cotwo', 'TILED': true, 'Version': '1.1.0' },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: null,

    })
});

//cotwo WFS-Layer
var cotwo_style = new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0)',
        width: 1,
    }),
});

var cotwo_styleLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: 'http://localhost:8585/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=abschluss_gdd:cotwo&outputFormat=application/json',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
    style: function (feature) {
        return cotwo_style;
    },
});

//Map_cotwo generation
var map1 = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map_cotwo',
    view: view,
    layers: [
    /* new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.OSM()
     }),*/
        cotwolayer,
        cotwo_styleLayer,
    ]
});

//Slider
var dates = ['year_1980', 'year_1981', 'year_1982', 'year_1983', 'year_1984', 'year_1985', 'year_1986', 'year_1987', 'year_1988', 'year_1989',
    'year_1990', 'year_1991', 'year_1992', 'year_1993', 'year_1994', 'year_1995', 'year_1996', 'year_1997', 'year_1998', 'year_1999',
    'year_2000', 'year_2001', 'year_2002', 'year_2003', 'year_2004', 'year_2005', 'year_2006', 'year_2007', 'year_2008', 'year_2009',
    'year_2010', 'year_2011', 'year_2012', 'year_2013', 'year_2014', 'year_2015', 'year_2016']

var sliderRange = document.getElementById("myRange");
sliderRange.max = dates.length - 1;

var dateValue = document.getElementById("date_value");
dateValue.innerHTML = dates[sliderRange.value].slice(1, 10);
cotwolayer[1].getSource().updateParams({ 'ELEVATION': dates[sliderRange.value] });

sliderRange.oninput = function () {
    dateValue.innerHTML = dates[this.value].slice(1, 10);
    cotwolayer[1].getSource().updateParams({ 'ELEVATION': dates[this.value] });
}
```

For that I tried using the Edit Layer > Dimensions > Elevation Parameter, but it seems like it doesn't work for SQL Attributes

Anyone got suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: The ELEVATION parameter is used to filter on a single attribute not change the value being queried. You need to change the actual attribute or rework your data so there is a single TIME attribute with different years in it